Understanding the Hilbert scheme of subvarieties of $\mathbb{CP}^n$
EDIT: migrated to MSE.
I am looking to get a more concrete understanding of the Hilbert scheme of projective subvarieties, specifically over $\mathbb{C}$, and to obtain good references on this subject. As my familiarity with algebraic geometry is restricted to only that over the field of complex numbers, I got lost with the formalism of schemes and functors of points presented in the more general accounts I've read online. References accessible to a differential geometer would be most helpful.
I am in particular hoping to understand the corollary of the theorem reproved in this paper:
COROLLARY: There are only a finite number of components in the Hilbert scheme parametrizing smooth surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^4$ not of general type.
I'll first ask a couple basic questions before my main one.
$1.$ What does a component of the Hilbert scheme actually parametrize? As in, if seen as a moduli space, do all the points in one component correspond to isomorphic surfaces?
$2.$ If this is the case, do we furthermore have that each point corresponds to the same type of embedding of said surface (as in any two embeddings are regularly homotopic)?
$3.$ Finally, my original, probably mistaken interpretation was to think that this result implies only finitely many smooth surfaces not of general type can embed in $\mathbb{CP}^4$. Is there any truth to this?

Nothing is true. Think of the Hilbert scheme parameterizing surfaces of degree $d$ in $\Bbb{P}^3$: there is just one component (a projective space), and two general points correspond to non-isomorphic surfaces.

There is the Hilbert — Birch — Schaps theorem for Cohen-Macaulay codimension two subvarieties of a smooth variety.  Presumably this characterizes your varieties as determinantal varieties.  Since the dualizing sheaf of a determinantal variety satisfies a version of “adjunction,” this might be the origin of bounded mess in your case.

Typo correction: "bounded mess" --> "boundedness" (autocorrect issue).

I'd accept 'bounded mess' as, at the least, not inaccurate.

@abx Thanks for the clarification. Now I must ask, at the risk of sounding very naive, why do we want to know there are only finitely many of these components? What's the point?
